# "either by" vs. "by either"

Tags: word-usage

Consider this sentence

> there are many verbs in English
>   that can be followed **either by** a gerund
>   or the to-infinitive.

I am aware that the main structure of the *that clause* is a passive voice, "followed ... by".

I am also aware that the use of "either ... or"

I don't know which one should I use, "either by" or "by either".

I searched a bit, "[either by](https://ell.stackexchange.com/search?q=%22either%20by%22)" got 140 hits and "[by either](https://ell.stackexchange.com/search?q=%22by%20either%22)" got 110 hits.

Is there some kind of rule applicable here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The better choice is "by either". So,
"... by either [a gerund] or [the to-infinitive]..."
Another option is "either [by a gerund] or [by the to-infinitive]", but that uses more words.

I have put braces in the two examples to highlight the structure of the either-or.

Comment: Thanks for your explanation. According to which, the example in my OP is grammatically incorrect because of the missing of the other "by", right?

Comment: Yes, although it is understandable.